# MVC5 project to IIS 7.5 error

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I move my project to another server then the server information following
OS:win server 2008
IIS: 7.5 version

I run my website then I got this error. I search internet to find solution.
I tried restart (v4.0.30319)aspnet_regiis.exe but it doesn't work. I got the same error...

This is my webconfig please help me to check if there have any problem...Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>

<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-NewTaipei.VirtualMuseum.Web-20160227024209.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-NewTaipei.VirtualMuseum.Web-20160227024209;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="MuseumEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Museum.Museum.csdl|res://*/Models.Museum.Museum.ssdl|res://*/Models.Museum.Museum.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=10.0.0.5;initial catalog=Museum;persist security info=True;user id=XXXX;password=XXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=Museum&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <!--
    如需 web.config 變更的說明，請參閱 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367。

    您可以在 <httpRuntime> 標記上設定下列屬性。
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web><customErrors mode="Off" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" />
    <!--<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />-->
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.0" maxRequestLength="1073741824" executionTimeout="3600" />
    <httpModules>

      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Redirect rule1 for 2016biennale" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{2016biennale:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Temporary" />
                </rule>
      </rules>
            <rewriteMaps>
                <rewriteMap name="2016biennale">
                    <add key="/biennale" value="/Exhibition/Index/3baf5bbb-55a7-4bcd-8ae6-1a55c44f1478" />
                    <add key="/collection" value="/Exhibition/Index/f2f308ea-d85d-4613-b9af-f4763bb02bf9" />
                </rewriteMap>
            </rewriteMaps>
    </rewrite>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.15.0" newVersion="1.2.15.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:Default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0" />
      </compiler>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

[image: My error message]

[image]

[image: My App Pool info]

Comment: I can't open any IIS function. The error message just display can't find \\?E:\Ntpc\web.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a similar error message due Conflict Between .Net app pool Versions !  I was trying to  a .Net 4 app in a .Net 2 app pool. when i updated  to 4.0 version it works for me please give a try!  for me it works

Comment: I have open .Net 4 framework in IIS. but win 2008 R2 just 3.5 can install.
You mean update framework to 4.0? Where can I see my framework version?

Comment: I download the program to update to framework 4.0. but I got the message is I already install framework 4.0 or high version in this computer.   So sad...

Comment: you can see that on App pool Properties?an please reply which is your currently using app pool  https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToSetAnIISApplicationOrAppPoolToUseASPNET35RatherThan20.aspx

Comment: I added one picture about my app pool. Please look at that. if there have any wrong...

Comment: bro i dont understand  your language ! i am sorry  ! There is an advanced setting for application! see what app pool is used for your application ! try change  different app pool check whether it works